# Kubernetes service doesn't expose external port

Tags: .net, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to host my first dotnet core application locally on Kubernetes.

Everything is working fine **but when I am trying to create service using z_service.yml file it doesn't expose port 8099 for accessing it externally in browser**.

```
$> kubectl apply -f .\z_service.yml
service/amazing-app-service created
```

However if I run `$> kubectl port-forward amazing-app 8099:80` command then it works and I can access the web application in browser with http://localhost:8099/

this is how services dashboard looks like

[image]

and the services status

[image]

Am I missing any configuration here?

Comment: Can you include the contents of `z_service.yml` in your question?

Comment: You can try to use the `LoadBalancer` type for the service.

Comment: @CharlesXu  , how to use that?

Comment: Are you trying to run it in Minikube?

Comment: No. It's with docker for desktop with Kubernetes enabled on it.

Comment: Change the service to set the `type with value `LoadBalancer` then it looks as `type: LoadBalancer`.

Comment: @CharlesXu , with `type: LoadBalancer` this works perfectly. thanks

Comment: '@CharlesXu' pls put your suggestions as answer. thx.

Comment: Well, I add the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it's `NodePort` for your service `amazing-app-service`. When you want to expose the service to the Internet. You should use the `LoadBalancer` type for the service. Just like:

```
type: LoadBalancer
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes, a service is an abstract layer that binds pods via the local network. 
If you need external access to your application one of the best ways is to use an [ingress object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

Comment: I have a dumb question: from [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0), I see that there are multiple ways of allowing external access to the service. I can understand why a LoadBalancer or ingress would work, but why *doesn't* his existing NodePort ip work?

Comment: One more thing to notice is External-IP is <none>, is this correct behavior?

Comment: @Kundan, In your case,  External-IP is ok. A cloud provider like Google Kubernetes Engine or Amazon Web Services uses External-IP to create a Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: @mmking, I'm not sure I understand the question correctly but NodePort only works for a local network (for k8s). LoadBalancer and Ingress makes the local network k8s available to the external network