# Exposing a pod to local enviroment for easy developing purposes?

Tags: visual-studio, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I am curently working with kubernetes, and trying to make a development process making it capable for developer to access services within a local kubernetes cluster? I would like it to keep it simple, and have for now tried `kubectl port-forward kafka 10000:9092` but this didn't seem to expose the pod to localhost:10000..

I've tried converting the kafka service to a nodeport, still with no luck - only way I could access it was by creating my application as dockerized application, and run the application in a docker container 
- meaning that running the exe file would not connect to it, but executing it using docker would make it work.

I've tried Kubectl proxy -  which doesn't work either -  I am not able to ping the clusterIp.

I have not tried with ingress or loadbalancer, as I find it a bit too elaborate, considering that this is only for developing purposes, and not something that should be production "secure"..

How do i easily expose the kafka service such that a console application on my laptop running kubernetes cluster locally can access it?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-headless
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: broker
    port: 9092
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9092
  selector:
    app: kafka
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  ports:
  - name: broker
    port: 9092
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9092
  selector:
    app: kafka
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka
  name: kafka
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  serviceName: kafka-headless
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -exc
        - |
          unset KAFKA_PORT && \
          export KAFKA_BROKER_ID=${HOSTNAME##*-} && \
          export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://${POD_IP}:9092 && \
          exec /etc/confluent/docker/run
        env:
        - name: POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS
          value: -Xmx1G -Xms1G
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: leader-zookeeper:2181
        - name: KAFKA_LOG_DIRS
          value: /opt/kafka/data/logs
        - name: KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR
          value: "1"
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -ec
            - /usr/bin/jps | /bin/grep -q SupportedKafka
          failureThreshold: 3
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        name: kafka-broker
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: kafka
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
          name: kafka
          protocol: TCP
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/kafka/data
          name: datadir
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
  updateStrategy:
    type: OnDelete
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: datadir
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka-pdb
  name: kafka-pdb
spec:
  maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
---
```

Answer (score 0):

To port forward to a service, you need to use `svc/` infront of the name. So your command would be either `kubectl port-forward svc/kafka 10000:9092` or `kubectl port-forward kafka-0 10000:9092`

On Windows, make sure windows firewall is not blocking kubectl.

*Reference:*
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod

---

You can also use `telepresence` to debug a existing service on cluster by swapping it local development version.

Install telepresence and use `telepresence --swap-deployment $DEPLOYMENT_NAME`

*Reference:*

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/local-debugging/#developing-or-debugging-an-existing-service

https://www.telepresence.io/reference/install

Comment: `kafka-0` is the pod, `kafka` is the service which isn't being accessible via localhost:10000

Comment: Yes you are right. Edited the answer. It should have worked. Did you get any error when you did port-forward? Is your pod actually running? Check the output of kubectl get pod. Check if your `kubectl` client's default namespace is changed.

Comment: telepresence is not supported on windows.

Comment: `kubectl port-forward svc/kafka 10000:9092
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:10000 -> 9092
Forwarding from [::1]:10000 -> 9092`

Comment: when the application try to connect I get this `Handling connection for 10000`
But my application ` 10.1.1.200:9092/0: Connect to ipv4#10.1.1.200:9092 failed: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond... (after 21013ms in state CONNECT)`

Comment: pod is running , default namespace

Comment: Can you check if your windows firewall is blocking kubectl?

Comment: turned it off -  still same

Comment: What is the OS of the nodes? Can you check if the pod logs shows if the there is any incoming connection?

Comment: Its hard to keep track... A lot happens.. 
The project itself is created with docker support, if I run the docker container I am able to hit it, 
But the exe file does not reach it.

Comment: What is the OS of the nodes? I see support for kubectl port-forward for windows nodes is recently added - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/75479

Comment: The pods are Base

Comment: I am using docker desktop

Comment: what does `The pods are Base ` mean? How did you create your kubernetes cluster? What is the operating system of your cluster nodes?

Comment: Cluster is created using Docker Desktop for windows. 
PODS image is based from Base

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I have some additional options for you to check:

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456239/how-to-expose-a-headless-service-for-a-statefulset-externally-in-kubernetes) uses an idea of `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` alongside other possible solutions.
2. I see from the comments that you are using Docker Desktop for Windows. You can try to use `type: LoadBalancer` service instead of `ClusterIP` or `NodePort`. I know it may sound wiered but I have seen few examples [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474073/kubernetes-service-doesnt-expose-external-port) showing that it actually works.

I am posting this as a community answer because the proposed solutions were not originally my ideas.

Please let me know if that helped.